# Rails - Output view path to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, output

I have a view generated by acts-as-taggable-on where I would like to output the name of the tag to the view inside an `<h1>` tag.

So far I'm able to output the name to the view using:

```
<h1>Icons matching <%= tag_path %></h1>
```

However when I do this it outputs both the tag name but also the root path of the application. So for instance if the tag is "notification" the browser outputs "Icons matching icons/notification".

How can I tell the browser to only output the second part of the path, ie. 
`<h1>Icons matching notifications</h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<h1>Icons matching <%= tag_path %></h1>
```

with

```
<h1>Icons matching <%= tag_path.split("/").last %></h1>
```